# How can I use a gem upgraded to work on Rails 3 when I am still on 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activesupport

I am trying to use a gem found on github that has been upgraded to work with Rails 3.0

I am still on 2.3.9, so I can a dependency error on ActiveSupport > 3.0.0

How can I:

- Find an earlier version on github (?)
- Tweak my app without doing a full upgrade to address the active support dependency?

https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the github homepage of the project, click "switch tags"
2. Find one that isn't rails3-only
3. Check it out

Faster: just do `gem install vestal_versions -v <correct version>`

Comment: is there a way to immediately tell if it works with 2.3.x, I just went to v 1.0.1 where it used config.gem and assumed that  must 2.3.8....sound good?

Comment: I don't know anything about this particular gem---not sure what version started requiring rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

> Find an earlier version on github ?

Github has a "switch tags" dropdown where you can select tags for previous versions. It appears for that gem there are currently 26 version tags available.

> Tweak my app without doing a full upgrade to address the active support dependency?

I don't think it's possible to install ActiveSupport 3.0.0 without upgrading the rest of Rails.

Comment: is there a way to immediately tell if it works with 2.3.x, I just went to v 1.0.1 where it used config.gem and assumed that  must 2.3.8....sound good?

Comment: @Angela yep, reasonable assumption.